# Taylor series manipulation

Tags: taylor-expansion

We know that inverse hyperbolics have logarithmic representations $$y = \text{artanh}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1−x}\right)$$ Using this relationship, can we alternatively build the Taylor polynomial for `artanh()` by plugging in $$\frac{1+x}{1−x}$$ for  everywhere in the Taylor polynomial for $\ln(x)$ (given by ln(x) = (x−1) − $\frac{1}{2}(x−1)^2 +\frac{1}{3}(−1)^3+...)$ and then multiplying the result by $\frac{1}{2}$? Why or why not?

Comment: When you do this, do you actually get a Taylor series?

Comment: Note that $\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\ln(1+x) - \ln(1-x)$ from which it is trivial to build the Taylor series. The Taylor series is unique, so once you have it there is no point finding a more complex method.

Comment: FYI, traditionally it is 'artanh', not 'arctanh'.

Comment: so in this case, plugging in $\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ into taylor series of ln(x) would not result in us getting a taylor series for artanh(x) because the coefficient would essentially be different?

Comment: No. Naively plugging in $\frac {1+x}{1-x}$ doesn't give the taylor series, because the result of doing so is not a power series. It will have $x$ in the denominator, which is not something power series have. You have to be cagey about how you do this, as Blitzer suggested.